# Ownable: New owner is the zero address

Tags: web3js, tokens, javascript, smart-contract-wallets, bsc

I'm trying to send **USDT** from my wallet to another wallet using **web3**, but I can't find the error here, I always end up ***sending BNB*** instead of the **USDT** that I have in my wallet.

I've checked out *tenderly* and sometimes it drops the error **Ownable: New owner is the zero address**, I understand with that that I'm sending the money to the **USDT** original address, but when I change the address on the to field it starts sending out **BNB** again instead of **USDT**.

Here is the code => ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/jlescalonap/2a5302cc6a56bfc2716969f2ea571d5f))

I've updated it by removing the **"value"** field on the *tx* execution, but besides I've passed the value on the **data** declaration, it's value still is **zero**, it's not sending **usdt** it keeps trying to send **BNB**.

Answer (score 0):

- You must remove the `value: usdtAmount,` because it is the value of bnb you send to your receiver, not usdt.
- The usdt value to transfer is in you data, where you use **web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall** to encode that!

Comment: Well the transaction was sucess but it again transfered BNB and not USDT, I'm trying to find out how or where to specify which is the coin I'm gonna transfer, since I've realized that I'm telling how many but not what... here is the TxId:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1b461ef575ce13dc421377d2140e612da617630a30e6f04dd48aa132fed3053f

Comment: @JoseEscalona You also need to set the USDT token as the `to` address in the transaction. Currently you're calling the `transfer` function on the address you're trying to transfer to, which wont transfer the USDT. You need to call the function on the USDT contract

Comment: So in the tx constant in the "to" I must use the usdt contract address right?, then where I should put the address that I'm trying to send the usdt to?